# Web servlet and connection

Tags: java, android

everyone

I am doing a school project for my university i developed my web app on netbeans already and i started doing my android app but im struggling to connect my android app with the servlet so i can send requests to the controller of my web app and take data from the apache database where i have saved all my information.
I know u can use json to send requests to the servlet but i dont know how to make it work.
I need to take form the database of my web app some datas like books and then send it to the android app so i could show it on my emulator

Thanks a lot!

```
package com.example.project;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.loopj.android.http.HttpGet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
v=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
}

public void Call(View v){

}
private class SendFeedback extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{
protected String doInBackground(String...Args){
    String output = null;
    try{
        URIBuilder builder = new
  URIBuilder("http://localhost:8080/TheOriginalProject/prova_Android");
        builder.setParameter("Username","Jack");
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(builder.build());
        HttpResponse httpResponse= httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
        output=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String s){
    try{

    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e+"Server Error", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: you will be getting an ip address, when you deploy your servelet, if it's local the you will have that instead of an ip address you will have to connect to that ip using any networking librarylike volly, retrofit(if you want speed) or httpUrlConnection.

Comment: I have deleted all my tries but i was more interested to know how it works using json so i could learn it idk with some example or a guide showing android code and the servlet code